# How to fetch data dynamically from an oracle table whose structure is known only at runtime using pl sql procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, procedure

I have been given a requirement to create a pl/sql procedure which will accept select statement as an input parameter. All data must be fetched from the query and printed in DBMS_OUTPUT.

I've researched native dynamic SQL and DBMS_SQL but was unable to figure out how to fetch and process data from a table whose structure is unknown.

Since the table name will be provided during run time, i just want to know how to store the data fetched from the query because i cant define variables or collections since the structure of table is unknown

Comment: Since the table name will be provided during run time, i just want to know how to store the data fetched from the query because i cant define variables or collections since the structure of table is unknown..please help..

Comment: One of the xxx_TAB_COLUMNS views (xxx in ('USER', 'ALL', 'DBA')) will be your friend here.

Answer (score 2):

First off, the requirement seems incredibly dubious.  You should never depend on data that is written to the `DBMS_OUTPUT` buffer-- it is entirely up to the client to enable a buffer, to ensure that the buffer is large enough, and to display the data from the buffer to the user.  By default, none of that will happen.  And writing a procedure to manipulate a table whose structure is completely unknown would be incredibly unusual.

If you are really determined, however, you would likely want to take Tom Kyte's [SQL Unloader](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:68212348056) which uses `DBMS_SQL` to write data from an arbitrary query to a flat file and modify it to write it to `DBMS_OUTPUT` instead.

Comment: Actually im supposed to create an excel data file of the rows fetched..i just mentioned DBMS_OUTPUT for simplicity..

Comment: i agree with @Justin here. PL/SQL is not the tool you are looking for. you need to look for ways of loading queries into excel. you can do that by defining a data source in excel to oracle and load directly. search for excel data source's in google.

Comment: @APPSfreak - If by "easier" you mean "without using `DBMS_SQL`", no.  If the number and types of the columns is unknown, you need the flexibility of `DBMS_SQL`.  That does make your PL/SQL much more complex than normal but that's the price you pay for that level of flexibility.  That's one of the reasons that the requirement doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open-source utility package for generating Excel readable files within PL/SQL.

https://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/

However, I would recommend you look into using a more general purpose language for your tool if at all possible. PL/SQL can be incredibly useful for database logic, but for interacting with the outside world, I expect you will achieve a more maintainable solution using something like Python or Java.

Although, as always YMMV :-)